# Green's function for fourth order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

Kind of a long shot, but is there a reference out there regarding the Green's function for
$$\frac{d^4}{dx^4}-2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+Id=(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-Id)^2$$
for boundary conditions $f(0)=f(1)=f''(0)=f''(1)=0$?

The reason I'm looking for this is that I'm trying to see if I can find bounds for $f'(0)$ and $f'(1)$ (i.e. at the end points) in terms of the inhomogeneous term by differentiating and estimating the Green's function.

Comment: Green's functions only exist for linear DEs, which this is not.

Comment: The 1 was meant to be the identity operator. I made the edit.

Comment: This is still not linear, the $+1$ was not the issue as I understood what you meant by that, it is standard notation.

Comment: Please tell me why this is nonlinear. Isnt it just a linear combination of derivatives? No products of derivatives are involved here

Comment: Oh I totally misunderstood the right hand side. I'll try to come up with a Green's function.